Questions about proof that Hilbert function is a polynomial in Evan Chen's "Napkin"
I have been reading through Evan Chen's "Napkin", but am having trouble understanding his proof that the Hilbert function of any ideal is eventually a polynomial.

Questions:

How can we rigorously show the first map $f \rightarrow f \cdot x_0$ is injective? My attempt:

Assume that the map is not injective. Then there exist polynomials $f, g$ such that $fx_0 = gx_0$ in [S / I], i.e.
$$
(f - g)x_0 \in I
$$
In turn, $\mathcal{V}(I) \in \mathcal{V}((f - g)x_0) = \mathcal{V}(f - g) \cup \mathcal{V}(x_0)$. From here, it seems we can use irreducibility...

This solution seems quite magical; what is the motivation for considering an additional hyperplane $H$?

Any insight would be deeply appreciated :)

For the sake of completeness, here is the reference : https://web.evanchen.cc/napkin.html

Intersecting with a hyperplane results in a variety whose dimension is $1$ less than that of the variety you started with, allowing you to do induction on dimension since there is an exact sequence that results. I suppose the motivation to prove this inductively is that Hilbert functions are easiest to understand in dimension $0$, i.e. for finite sets of points.

As for your first question, my first instinct is to ask if you've studied ring or group theory much before. Because there is a standard approach to showing that a homomorphism (of groups, rings, modules over a fixed ring, etc.) is injective, namely showing that the kernel is trivial. The approach you are taking is standard when working with plain sets, but in the presence of some algebraic structure it is unnecessarily confusing. I ask this because trying to learn about varieties without any abstract algebra background is like trying to do calculus before you can factor a quadratic polynomial.

@TabesBridges I have studied abstract algebra before — if you have a solution involving it, I (hopefully) would be able to understand it :)

It's just a small change to the argument; instead of considering two polynomials with the same image under the map, consider a single $f$ such that $f\cdot x_0 = 0$ and see if you can prove that $f$ is necessarily $0$.
